# Javascript cleanest way to distinct array based on object property

Tags: javascript

So I have an array of statuses and I want to get distinct values based on an element property `ProductOrderStatusTypeID`. I have one implementation but I want the cleanest way of doing that.

My list:

```
[{
  StatusID : 1,
  Name : "Open",
  ProductOrderStatusType : 'Initial'
  ProductOrderStatusTypeID : 1
},{
  StatusID : 3,
  Name : "Closed",
  ProductOrderStatusType : 'Final'
  ProductOrderStatusTypeID : 2
},
{
  StatusID : 3,
  Name : "Pending",
  ProductOrderStatusType : 'Initial'
  ProductOrderStatusTypeID : 1
}]
```

Expected output:

```
[{
  ProductOrderStatusType : 'Initial',
  ProductOrderStatusTypeID : 1
},{
  ProductOrderStatusType : 'Final',
  ProductOrderStatusTypeID : 2
}]
```

My code:

```
function getDistinctProductOrderStatusType(statuses) {
    return statuses.reduce(function (result, status) {
        var existingStatus = result.filter(function (res) {
            return res.ProductOrderStatusTypeID === status.ProductOrderStatusTypeID;
        })[0];
        if (!existingStatus) {
            result.push({
                ProductOrderStatusTypeID: status.ProductOrderStatusTypeID,
                ProductOrderStatusType: status.ProductOrderStatusType
            });
        }
        return result;
    }, []);
}
```

Comment: Probably best suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - since your code works but you want a suggestion to make it different.

Comment: Make sense guys thanks . i will post it there

Comment: Reducing to an object or `Map` using the "groupBy" values as keys is a lot more efficient than running `filter()` each iteration...  then get values from that object

Comment: Statuses is array that i have mentioned in my question as 'My List'

Comment: @charlietfl any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const stat = [{
    StatusID: 1,
    Name: "Open",
    type: 'Initial', // !!! I renamed properties for simplicity sake
    typeID: 1
  }, {
    StatusID: 3,
    Name: "Closed",
    type: 'Final',
    typeID: 2
  }, {
    StatusID: 3,
    Name: "Pending",
    type: 'Initial',
    typeID: 1
  }
];

const distinctStat = arr => arr.reduce((a, {type, typeID}) =>
  a.some(ob => ob.typeID === typeID) ? a : a.concat({type, typeID})
, []);

console.log( distinctStat(stat) );
```

In case you find it more easier to name the properties you're **not** interested in collecting (like i.y.e: `StatusID` and `Name`) than you could go for the rest element:

```
const distinctStat = arr => arr.reduce((a, {StatusID, Name, ...r}) =>
  a.some(ob => ob.typeID === r.typeID) ? a : a.concat(r)
, []);
```

(same output as above)

### Info:

Although we could, in the above code [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
 is used instead of [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
 because we don't need to return the entire object but just a boolean (as quickly as possible).